# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int?>'

Tags: c#, linq

```
class first
{
    private int? firstID;
}

class second
{
    private int secondID;
    private int secondField;
}

public override Expression<Func<first, bool>> FirstFilter()
{
    Contex db = new Contex();
    List<second> list = (from p in db.second select p).ToList();

    return b => list.Select(p => p.secondID).Contains(b.firstID);
}
```

and I have error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I have tried many different ways, but I just don't know how can I fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
list.Select(p => p.secondID).Cast<int?>().Contains(b.firstID);
```

You are getting the problem, because `list.Select(p => p.secondID)` will be an `IEnumerable<int?`, but because firstID is `int` (non-nullable), overload resolution cannot determine a valid overload of Contains to call. You cannot implicitly convert from `IEnumerable<int?>` to `IEnumerable<int>`. The Cast extension method works by casting each element to int.

As mentioned in another answer, you could also simply pass in a non-nullable int into Contains:

```
list.Select(p => p.secondID).Contains(b.firstID ?? 0);
```

But, do be aware that this might not be want. If the first list contains `0`, and `firstID` is null, the result will be true, because you pass in 0 when the value is null.The Cast version of the expression returns false when `firstID` is null.

Comment: perfect , thanks very much, i knew where is a problem, but din't know how to cast

Comment: awesome dude, stuff like this makes the stack the tops!

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a default value for `firstID` if it is null:

```
return b => list.Select(p => p.secondID).Contains(b.firstID ?? 0);
```